# Exit Conflicts in Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, jframe, dispose

I met another problem fixing two GUIs in my Java Program. Say we have a new JFrame:

```
public class guiOne {

public static void main (String [] agrs) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    JButton b = new JButton();
    JPanel p = new JPanel();

    b.setSize(100,100);
    f.setTitle("New JFrame");
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setSize(300,300);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    p.add(b);
    f.add(b);
}
```

When I click the new button, a new JFrame appears. The problem i get is when I add this code:

```
System.exit(guiOne);
```

All exits. I only want the guiOne to exit as soon as I start the new JFrame. Why does it close everything up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`f.setVisible(true);` must be last code line in contructor for Container

1) never create a new [JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) as another Top-Level Container, use [JDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) with parent to the `JFrame` and/or with `setModal()/ ModalityTypes` if required

2) don't create a new `Top-Level Container`, create this contaainer once times and reuse that with `getComtentPane.removeAll()`

3) you have look at [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for simple and easy implementations, more confotable as playing with another `JFrame/JDialog` on the screen

4) [JTabbedPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html) is another way how to do it

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should be using [`f.dispose()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose%28%29) instead. [`System.exit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit%28int%29) stops the whole jvm. Note that you can use [`setDefaultCloseOperation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29) on the frame so that you close it using the window managers hooks (eg Alt-F4 etc).

---

### Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Open new frame") {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            // create new frame
            JFrame newFrame = new JFrame("New Frame");
            newFrame.add(new JLabel("new frame..."));
            newFrame.pack();
            newFrame.setVisible(true);
            newFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            // dispose the old frame
            frame.dispose();
        }
    }));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: could you explain by the way what the throws IOexception do? Thanks

Comment: oh okay. I have been reading some Java codes and can't understand the differentiation of extends and implements as well as throws.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you want to happen when the windows closes. EXIT_ON_CLOSE means that the JVM will shut down when the window is closed, and that is not normally what you want to happen. DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE will release the resources held by the JFrame, and is what you use for a window not opened a lot. HIDE_ON_CLOSE is for when you just want the window to go invisible, but still maintain hold of the resources. Makes it quicker to open the window, and is used when you will be using a window over and over again.

I suggest you do the following:

```
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```